# Android Sync needed in writing files and

Tags: android, file, synchronization, android-sensors

I have an android application that runs a thread thar reads the sensor values and writes them to a file after 500ms.The values of sensors(accelerometer) are declared as global and change inside the sensorChange() event.I do not have a lock on read and write operations.Should I have some kind of a synchronized mechanism or is it fine as one event performs the reading and the other writing.

eg,For Accelerometer I have a global variable xA,yA,zA,which are written into file 4 times every second and are updated in sensorChangeEvent().

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 threads - one reads a variable and another writes to the same variable, then you have to synchronize the access

Comment: no I simply have an method that updates the values and a thread reading them.wat say??

Comment: do you call this method which updates the values in a separate thread?